# Avoiding parsing format string while still using printf-buffering

Tags: c, printf

In a C-program, I use the line: `printf("%c", WORD_SEP);` which I think is self-explanatory.

As far as I understand, printf will parse the Format-String "%c" and replace it with the character WORD_SEP **at runtime**. This of course is completely avoidable because WORD_SEP is a compiler #define and will therefore never changes.

I could hardcode `printf("*");` which will be faster, but of course I would like to keep the #define for maintainability - also it will still be not optimal because printf would still have to parse the string.

Is there a better way?

Comment: maybe `putchar(WORD_SEP)` is what you want

Comment: Actually, if you turn on aggressive optimizations, the compiler will optimize out this anyway and it will become `putc(WORD_SEP);`.

Comment: I can't imagine the amount of 'faster' you're going to get out of this kind of optimization could possibly make a difference.  Are you experiencing problems related to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-formatted single character printing:

`putc()`, `putchar()` and `fputc()`

Non-formatted string printing:

`fputs()`, and my (not-so-)favorite `puts()`

On a side note, avoid using `"*"` instead of `'*'` because, `"*"` creates a space in the memory with two bytes, one for `*` and the other for `\0`. Wherever you want 1 single character, use `'*'` instead of `"*"`

Comment: The two bytes vs. one is rarely an issue these days, even on embedded systems. The more significant problem is that their types differ (`char` vs. `char[2]`), and this can lead to confusion.

Comment: No problem with what you said, just for the record :) My principle: "I rather write inefficient and readable code than efficient and unreadable code."

Comment: @H2CO3: The good thing about doing that is that your compiler will take your readable unefficient code and make it more efficient than other people's unreadable "efficient" code. So you win on both grounds :)

Comment: @SecurityMatt And after all, that's true :)

Comment: Aniket: Not only is that an invalid premature optimisation, but it's based on invalid presumptions. What is `sizeof 'a'`? Test your theory: `printf("sizeof 'a' is %zu\n", sizeof 'a');` (http://ideone.com/jXh0Ou, if you're lazy)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue ?? what are you getting at?

Comment: Uhh, I'd have thought it'd be obvious. `'*'` is an int value, not a char value. Can you think of any systems where an int value occupies more than 1 character? If so, then how can you state definitively that `'*'` occupies 1 single character?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue "*" creates a string, in the memory, of two characters(which means, it occupies two memory locations), then a pointer to it is used to pass it around(which means additional 4 bytes of data) .. what are you getting at?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue also, the C compiler may optimize that too, to use 1 byte to store the character, where you're using 6 bytes to pass it around - do you not think that is too much?

Comment: Do you know what an abstract machine is? In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An 
actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its 
value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, printf will parse the Format-String "%c" and replace it with the character WORD_SEP at runtime. This of course is completely avoidable because WORD_SEP is a compiler #define and will therefore never changes.

And gcc does optimize `printf("%c", WORD_SEP);` into a call to `putchar('*')`:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define WORD_SEP '*'

int main() {
    printf("%c", WORD_SEP);
}
```

Output asm:

```
g++ -S --verbose-asm -o - -DNDEBUG -g -Wall -Wextra -march=native -O3 test.cc | c++filt > test.s
```

test.s:

```
main:
    subq    $8, %rsp    
    movl    $42, %edi   
    call    putchar 
    xorl    %eax, %eax  
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

Also gcc optimizes `printf("..." /* no arguments */)` into `puts()` to avoid parsing the format string with no format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm not misreading the question, but if you want to ultimately do something like

```
printf("abc %c xyz", WORD_SEP);
```

without actually having this constant word separator inserted at runtime, you could first do

```
#define WORD_SEP "*"
```

and then do

```
printf("abc " WORD_SEP " xyz");
```

which will result in the format string being created at compile time.  As mentioned in the comments below, in this case you would need to be careful about having a `%` character in `WORD_SEP` since it's now part of the format string.

Comment: #define WORD_SEP "%" // oh noes!

Comment: Thanks @SecurityMatt, I've edited to include a disclaimer regarding `%`.